# iOS Swift 3 Core Data - Fatal Error attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I need some help debugging an error that I get when making about 150 calls to core data to save the context.  After determining if I need to update the core data record because it doesn't exist, or the CloudKit record is more current, I save the core data context for each asynchronous call, but only think that I am calling the save once per call.  Can I get some help to understand where the recursion is occurring?

```
2017-06-17 12:13:51.295312-0400 My Toy Chest[2161:2177589] fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=132001 "(null)" UserInfo={message=attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted, stack trace=(
0   CoreData                            0x0000000188e8802c <redacted> + 164
1   My Toy Chest                        0x0000000100109e0c _TFC12My_Toy_Chest11AppDelegate11saveContextfT_T_ + 172
2   My Toy Chest                        0x00000001000de61c _TFFFC12My_Toy_Chest21ActionFigureSpecifics24setActionFigureSpecificsFT_T_U_FTGSqCSo8CKRecord_GSqPs5Error___T_U0_FT_T_ + 8464
3   My Toy Chest                        0x00000001000946d4 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 44
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101549a50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101549a10 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010154eb78 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1204
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186b3d0c8 <redacted> + 12
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186b3ace4 <redacted> + 1572
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186a6ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001884d4074 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKit                               0x000000018cd25058 UIApplicationMain + 208
12  My Toy Chest                        0x000000010010a668 main + 76
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000185a7959c <redacted> + 4
)}, [AnyHashable("stack trace"): <_NSCallStackArray 0x17464c1b0>(
0   CoreData                            0x0000000188e8802c <redacted> + 164,
1   My Toy Chest                        0x0000000100109e0c _TFC12My_Toy_Chest11AppDelegate11saveContextfT_T_ + 172,
2   My Toy Chest                        0x00000001000de61c _TFFFC12My_Toy_Chest21ActionFigureSpecifics24setActionFigureSpecificsFT_T_U_FTGSqCSo8CKRecord_GSqPs5Error___T_U0_FT_T_ + 8464,
3   My Toy Chest                        0x00000001000946d4 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 44,
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101549a50 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24,
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101549a10 _dispatch_client_callout + 16,
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010154eb78 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1204,
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186b3d0c8 <redacted> + 12,
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186b3ace4 <redacted> + 1572,
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186a6ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424,
10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001884d4074 GSEventRunModal + 100,
11  UIKit                               0x000000018cd25058 UIApplicationMain + 208,
12  My Toy Chest                        0x000000010010a668 main + 76,
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000185a7959c <redacted> + 4
)
, AnyHashable("message"): attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted]: file /Users/jasongloor/Documents/Development/My Toy Chest/My Toy Chest/AppDelegate.swift, line 211
```

Code leading to the crash.  The code below is called once for each action figure in an array.

```
func setActionFigureSpecifics() {
    // check for specifics already set to prevent multiple calls
    if isActionFigureSpecificSetFromICloud {

        self.delegate?.updateActionFigureSpecificsModel()
    }
    else {
        //////////
        // Core Date Fetch Request
        //////////
        let isNewCoreDataRecord = setCoreDataActionFigureSpecifics()

        //////////
        // iCloud fetch request
        //////////
        if SharedData.sharedInstance.isUserPreferenceToUseICloud == true {
            isActionFigureSpecificSetFromICloud = true

            // Private Database
            let privateDatabase = SharedData.sharedInstance.privateDatabase

            let actionFigureSpecificsRecordId = CKRecordID(recordName: actionFigureSpecificsGlobalUniqueId)

            privateDatabase!.fetch(withRecordID: actionFigureSpecificsRecordId){ [unowned self] record, error in
                var ckError: CKError?

                if let cloudKitError = error as? CKError {
                    ckError = cloudKitError
                }

                if (ckError != nil && (ckError?.code != CKError.Code.unknownItem)) {
                }
                else {

                        if record != nil { // check for records found

                            self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord = record
                            let iCloudUpdateDate = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kUpdateDate) as! Date

                            // set the core data record from the cloud if the record is new
                            if isNewCoreDataRecord == true {
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveTheFigure = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kHaveTheFigure) as! Bool
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveFigureCount = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kHaveFigureCount) as! Int64
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantTheFigure = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kWantTheFigure) as! Bool
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantFigureCount = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kWantFigureCount) as! Int64
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate = iCloudUpdateDate as NSDate

                                SharedData.sharedInstance.appDelegate.saveContext()
                            }

                            let coreDataUpdateDate = self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate! as Date

                            // determine which data is more current by date

                            if coreDataUpdateDate < iCloudUpdateDate { // reset core data
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveTheFigure = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kHaveTheFigure) as! Bool
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveFigureCount = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kHaveFigureCount) as! Int64
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantTheFigure = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kWantTheFigure) as! Bool
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantFigureCount = self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.object(forKey: kWantFigureCount) as! Int64
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate = iCloudUpdateDate as NSDate

                                //  Recursion Error occurs here
                                //  Recursion Error occurs here
                                SharedData.sharedInstance.appDelegate.saveContext()
                            }
                            else if coreDataUpdateDate > iCloudUpdateDate { // reset iCloud data
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveTheFigure as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kHaveTheFigure)
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.haveFigureCount as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kHaveFigureCount)
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantTheFigure as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kWantTheFigure)
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.wantFigureCount as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kWantFigureCount)
                                self.actionFigureSpecificsRecord!.setObject(self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate as CKRecordValue?, forKey: kUpdateDate)

                                #if DEBUG
                                    print("Specifics reset iCloud data: \(String(describing: self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.actionFigureRecordName)) coreData \(coreDataUpdateDate) and iCloud \(iCloudUpdateDate)")
                                #endif

                                self.saveActionFigureSpecifics(forUpdateDate: self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate!)
                            }


                            self.delegate?.updateActionFigureSpecificsModel()
                        }
                        else {
                             if self.isActionFigureSpecificsCoreDataDefaultValues() == false {

                                self.saveActionFigureSpecifics(forUpdateDate: self.actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate!)
                            }

                            self.delegate?.updateActionFigureSpecificsModel()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Fetch Request

```
func setCoreDataActionFigureSpecifics() -> Bool {
    var isNewCoreDataRecord = false

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ActionFigureSpecificsCoreData")

    // Add Predicate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", "actionFigureRecordName", actionFigureGlobalUniqueId)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate])

    do {
        let recordArray = try SharedData.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [ActionFigureSpecificsCoreData]

        // check for records
        if recordArray.count == 0 {
            isNewCoreDataRecord = true

            actionFigureSpecificsCoreData = ActionFigureSpecificsCoreData(context: SharedData.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext)
            actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.actionFigureRecordName = actionFigureGlobalUniqueId
            // want it and have it are set to defaults by core data
            actionFigureSpecificsCoreData!.updateDate = NSDate()

            SharedData.sharedInstance.appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
        else if recordArray.count == 1 {
            for record in recordArray {
                actionFigureSpecificsCoreData = record

                ...

                delegate?.updateActionFigureSpecificsModel()
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Multiple action figure specific records fetched for \(actionFigureGlobalUniqueId)")
            abort()
        }
    } catch {
        let saveError = error as NSError
        print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
    }

    return isNewCoreDataRecord

}
```

Comment: Do you have a fetchedResultsController in your project anywhere?  Modifying core-data from inside any of these delegate callback will lead to this error.

Comment: I don't believe so, but I added in the fetch request code that is only called once per action figure.

Comment: What thread is privateDatabase.fetch returning on?  If it is the main thread then then DispatchQueue.main.async is not needed.  If it is not the main thread then you are illegally accessing a context from the wrong thread.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the code where you register for core-data changed notifications?

Comment: I removed the DispatchQueue.main.async.  I am not specifically registering for core-data changes.  If listening is the default behavior, then I likely am getting callbacks.  I do listen for external cloudKit changes, but that code is not firing.  I marked the specific line that is causing the recursion.  If I comment the saveContext listed, I do not get the recursion error.

Comment: I still don't know what caused the recursion, but when I removed all of the save calls during the initialization of the record and only save the cloudKit records when the cloudKit records were updated, it worked fine.  Since the error didn't occur every time, I am assuming that there must have been some sort of race condition where I was calling save concurrently from two different function calls.  I moved the core Data context saves to the viewWillDisappear that occurs well after the load and it works fine.  I also have a context save when the application closes.

Answer (score 0):

You're code's a bit inter-connected which makes it tricky, but you should re-read Apple's documentation on concurrency and CoreData. If all access to the context is done properly, this error should go away.